# How to disable manual editing of react-admin DateInput

Tags: react-native, material-ui, react-admin

I try to simply disable the manual editing of the DateInput of react-admin. I just want to be able to pick a date (green) insteed of allowing the user to enter the dates (Red)
So the control should be disabled in a way, but still picking date should be possible.

[image]

I tried as follow but did not succeed

```
import { DateInput } from "react-admin";
<DateInput editable={false} source={'myDate'}></DateInput>
```

How to achieve this?

"react-admin": "3.10.4"
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"

dependencies from package.json:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
"@types/react": "^16.9.0",
"final-form": "^4.18.5",
"final-form-arrays": "^3.0.2",
"final-form-focus": "^1.1.2",
"final-form-set-field-data": "^1.0.2",
"final-form-set-field-touched": "^1.0.1",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"immutable": "4.0.0-rc.12",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"proxy-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
"query-string": "^6.12.1",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-admin": "3.10.4",
"react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-final-form": "^6.3.3",
"react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.5.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
"react-time-ago": "^6.2.0",
"seamless-immutable": "^7.1.3",
"typescript": "^3.7.0",
```

Comment: Which package do you use ?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I added more info like dependencies.